# Names for different age group

Tags: terminology

What are the age group names for each increment of a decade,starting from 0 and up?  i.e. Octogenarian or teenager ??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://theelderlies.wordpress.com/2006/10/02/age-by-decade/ offers

- Denarian: Someone age 10 to 19.
- Vicenarian: Someone in his or her twenties.
- Tricenarian: Someone in his or her thirties.
- Quadragenarian: Someone in his or her forties.
- Quinquagenarian: Someone in his or her fifties.
- Sexagenarian: Someone in his or her sixties.
- Septuagenarian: Someone in his or her seventies.
- Octogenarian: Someone in his or her eighties.
- Nonagenarian: Someone in his or her nineties.
- Centenarian: Someone 100 or more.
- Supercentenarian: Someone 110 years old or more (no upper limit).

This does not address 0 to 9, I offer wee-uns.

Comment: Someone between the ages of 13 and 19 has always been and always will be a teenager.

Comment: @Mari-LouA At least since 1922.  http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=teenager&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: And if you make it to the age of 1000, you become a _millennarian_.

Comment: “A **tween** is a person who is between the ages of 10 to 12 years old.” – [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tween_%28demographic%29), which links to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tween).